# Mass updating a property in a class object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a class that bulk loads data from an object list into a database table. On occasion one of the date fields (ReadingTimeCdt) being passed should be set as current time for all records in that list, so I have a parameter (boolean) that checks if that's the case and if it is sets the ReadingTimeCdt the current time. I am using a foreach loop to set the date to current, but these objects can be quite large and performance can become an issue. Is there a way to simply set all ReadingTimeCdt in the object to currentTime without using a loop?

Here's the code I have.

```
        public void InsertBulkLoad(List<Location> rec, bool currentDate)
        {

            try
            {
                if(currentDate == true){
                    foreach (Location vr in rec)
                    {
                        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                        vr.ReadingTimeCdt = currentTime;
                    }
                }

                using (LiveContext entity = new LiveContext())
                {
                    entity.Location.AddRange(rec);
                    entity.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Exception code here...
            }

        }
```

Comment: `performance can become an issue` have you 100% positively identified that the `issue` is inside the `foreach` loop part of the code? also, one thing you can do is move `DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;` outside the loop which will gain some performance for you

Comment: Yes, if I remove the loop performance is fine. This class deals with thousands of rows of data, so I am not surprised the loop slows things down.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that if you initialize the property in the class. I mean, you are going to set it to current time anyway, and during the saving EF will have to loop through all of those objects anyway.

```
public class Location
{
    .....
    public DateTime ReadingTimeCdt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that yesterday and kept getting an error, but I went ahead and tried it again just now and it worked. Not sure what I did wrong yesterday, but this is the solution I will go with for now.  Thank you.